# Updated Catel from 5.12.4 to 5.12.15: runtime error on every EventToCommand line inViews

Tags: catel

After updating Catel from 5.12.4 to 5.12.15 every view with xaml parts like this:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="...">
        <catel:EventToCommand Command="..." />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

causes runtime error:
An instance of type "EventToCommand" cannot be added to a collection of type "TriggerActionCollection". Only items of type 'T' are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the change to move to the (actively maintained) Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors package. Please use the correct package moving forward and all should be good.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I can't manage the change properly

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I can't manage the change properly. Updateted to Catel 5.12.16, added the latest Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors 1.1.31, changed xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" to xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors", and I got **An instance of type "..." cannot be added to a collection of type "BehaviorCollection". Only items of type 'T' are allowed.**

Comment: Remove the reference to the old behaviors sdk. If it's still playing up, please check the available paid support options we provide